# How to merge cell in a column if cell above it has content but itself is blank

Tags: vba, excel

Here is what trouble me:

For cells in column P, for example P3, if both P2 & B3 is not blank, but P3 is blank, then merge P2 with P3. And go on next cell in column P until respective cell in column B(for instance: B8) is blank, then stop.

```
       B      ....      P
 1  Monitor            Tom
 2   Mouse             Ann
 3  Keyboard
 4  Sticker
 5  Speaker            John
 6   Cable
 7    Fan              Rose
 8
```

So for table above, I want to merge P2:P4 & P5:P6.
I've tried several time with my poor vba skill, but failed...

This code is what I've found in this website, and I've tried to edit it and see if this can solve my problem, but it doesn't work...

```
Sub Merge()
LR = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
For i = 1 To LR
If ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 1).Value <> "" And ActiveSheet.Cells(i + 1, 1).Value = "" And ActiveSheet.Cells(i + 1, 2).Value <> "" Then
   u = i + 1
   Do While ActiveSheet.Cells(u, 1).Value = "" And ActiveSheet.Cells(u, 2) <> ""
        u = u + 1
    Loop
    ActiveSheet.Range("A" & i & ":A" & (u - 1)).Select
    With Selection
        .Merge
        .BorderAround Weight:=xlMedium
        .WrapText = True
        '.VerticalAlignment = x1VAlignTop
        '.HorizontalAlignment = xlLeft
    End With
    Sheets(DataSheet).Range("B" & i & ":B" & (u - 1)).BorderAround Weight:=xlMedium
    i = u + 1
End If
```

Next i
End Sub

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Dim i As Integer, a As String, b As String, c As Integer, d  As Integer
i = 11
a = "B"
b = "P"
c = 0
d = 0
While Range(a & i) <> ""
    If Range(b & i) = "" Then
        If c = 0 And i > 1 Then
            c = i - 1
            d = 1
        Else
            d = d + 1
        End If
    Else
        If c > 0 And d > 0 Then
            Range(b & c & ":" & b & (c + d)).Merge
        End If
        c = 0
        d = 0
    End If
    i = i + 1
Wend
If c > 0 And d > 0 Then
    Range(b & c & ":" & b & (c + d)).Merge
End If
```

Comment: This can only work if my data starts from row 1, right ? What code should I add if I want this function to work starting from P11 ? Because above P11 are other things such as headlines and dates

Comment: Then just replace the second line with the number you wish: e.g. i = 11

Comment: Thank you very much!! Now works perfectly! Really appreciate your help!!

Comment: I am glad to be of service.

Comment: These days, I tried to modify your code so that it can select all blank cells first and then merge all in once.(For example, select P2:P4, then merge; instead of merge P2:P3, then unmerge, and merge P2:P4 again )   I have tried to use resize, but it doesn't work. Can I have any suggestion from you ?

Comment: Please never use select, it slows the code down unnecessarily. So you want the same behaviour, but instead of merging one by one it should be merged once for every blank area?

Comment: oh! I have read articles about not using select. Yes I was trying to merge once for every blank area, but not all blank area in the column. (I am just curious whether this is possible ^.^ , recently I have found a lot of fun learning about vba, thanks for you help BTW)

Comment: Yes, it is possible to do it and it would be an improvement to my code :). I'll take a look at it this afternoon.

Comment: Try the now edited code, it should work with the improvement.

Comment: That works perfectly! You just give me another lesson. Let me study the logic behind this code. Thank you again for your teaching!

Comment: Feel free to ask questions if necessary.